# Send data on a database server on Android

Tags: android, database

I have a sample app on which the user log in with Facebook. I want to send his information like name, email age and gender to a server where I can be able to see all the data from all the users who used the application.
How I can achieve this in a simple way ? 
I read a little about `Parse` - is this a good approach for what I need?

Comment: You have to user Graph_API for retrieving details regarding email etc.. and send this data through web service to insert into table in server side..

Comment: if u r getting info from facebook .. write one php webservice to send data to server

Comment: @Subburaj: I have user info, but I do not have a server to send to.. I have never worked on a server side app on Android and I do not know from where to start with..

Comment: @Shreeshesh: that the problem - I do not have a server... and I'm not sure where to start from; I do not know php - just java

Comment: For that you have to write API service using java by creating a local DB in your system and make connection to that service in your android code. Your service code will insert data into database..

Comment: Use Google Spreadsheet API for android ..... first save in spreadsheet from app and retrive spreadsheet content in computer using google spreadhsset api for java .......... its bit complex....

Comment: @Subburaj: it seems complex, but maybe is the solution I need to use, but I cannot use my system since is not opened all the time, maybe I need to look at a payed solution....

Comment: @Shreeshesh: I rather not go with using Google Spreadsheet API since I saw they have some limits on the data you can add... I'm wonder if you used Parse?

Comment: I just gave an idea for testing in your local system. When you think about production you should go for some payed solutions..

Comment: no limit for spreadsheet api plz chk again

Comment: Because I wanted a simple solution and because I wanted to be fast, I ended up, for now at least, by using Parse: https://parse.com  Thanks guys for your advices, maybe in the future I will consider them.